# accidentally deleted libvirt group, how to restore it

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, groups

I accidently run the command

```
sudo groupdel libvirt
```

and after that my virtual machine qemu stop working says this,
[image]

also after deleting group I'm not able to see libvirt in groups command.
how to restore that, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you could just do :

```
addgroup --system libvirt
```

Comment: This should be a comment. not an answer

Comment: It is a valid answer and works, or you can re-install the package which will recreate the group if it doesn't exist. Like `apt install --reinstall libvirt-daemon-system` - even any update would run the same code. Only if you didn't completely remove it, then the maintainer scripts can not know if that was intentional and leave things as-is.